# Creating default.aspx.designer.cs file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2005

I need the file "default.aspx.designer.cs" which is not auto generating even for the first time when I am trying to create a ASP.NET web application using C#

Everyone says delete the default.aspx.designer.cs code and then click on "convert to web application" but I can neither find the file default.aspx.designer.cs nor the option "convert to web application"

How to auto generate a designer.cs file in Visual Studio 2005 using c# ASP.NET web application?

Comment: How many .aspx files are we talking?  If it is only handful, you'd better off creating the file yourself with partial class keyword

Comment: Ummm do we even have designer.cs file for ASP projects...i have been making ASP.Net projects forlong time and have never seen designer.cs file for it.. its there in winforms.. but in ASP.Net it is automatically created when you run your application..

Comment: @Shekhar - Well, there is very much need of creating a designer file when you work with MSBUILD.exe compiler to improve the security of code. This file is very much required to perform obfuscation. Anyways I came to know that its not possible to generate it, I coded it manually.. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Are you sure that you have web application? Sure it's not a web site?

Comment: yeah! but I came to know that this designer file do not generate in ASP.NET it seems. So, I coded it. The use of this to improve code security while performing obfuscation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you need the designer file for? When I create asp .net, I only have the default.aspx and default.aspx.cs underneath that.

Comment: yeah... loganj... of course you are right but a designer file is required to obfuscate the code and to make a dll. Anyways I coded the file and its working fine. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I think you're working in a web SITE project as opposed to a web APPLICATION project. With the latter VS will auto-generate the .designer.cs file when you create a new page/control.

See here for the difference when creating: http://bit.ly/hGa7jC